# Looping a function through multiple files in a folder using Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, translate

I have multiple .csv files in a folder named the following way:

```
parts-1.csv 
parts-2.csv
.
.
parts-104.csv
```

(each file contains only a single column)

I am trying to get the following translator function in Python to go through each of these files, translate and save them as a new file.

```
data = pd.read_csv("parts4.csv")
translator = Translator()
translations = {}
for column in data.columns:
    unique = data[column].unique()
    for element in unique:
        translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text
for i in translations.items():
    print(I)
```

I am also trying to save the translated files in the following format:

```
parts-1-translated.csv 
.
.
parts-104-translated.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import glob, os

for filename in glob.iglob('./**', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename): # filter dirs
        print(filename)
```

From **python** >= 3.5 onward, you can use `**` in glob to get all subdirs.

This will output something like:

```
./records/parts-1.csv
./records/parts-2.csv
```

Comment: Many thanks! Please excuse if this is a super basic question but I am new to Python and struggling a bit - how could you please help me understand how to specify the data variable? (I had missed specifying this line of code I have been using, but I have added it to the question now).

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by data variable? @epsilon

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to read the documentation of [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Example:

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_PATH = Path(...)

RECORDS_PATH = BASE_PATH / "records"

for file in RECORDS_PATH.iterdir():
    if not file.is_file():
        continue
    data = file.read_text() # or read_bytes()
    # Translate things
    translated_file = file.with_name(f"{file.stem}-translasted.csv")
    translated_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I just tried this but unfortunately, it is throwing the following error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 53: character maps to <undefined> I have just started learning Python and I am struggling to understand why this is happening.

Comment: @epsilon, I think you are using Python 2.7 (try `python --version` to check it). On MacOS I think it's standard and I would guess you use a Mac. Try executing your code with `python3 my_file.py` instead of `python my_file.py`.

Answer (score 0):

One quick soln since you know how many files there are is the following -  you just loop through the names of the file to read it and then perform the translation as you propose. Output can similarly be generated by changing the filename a bit within the loop.

```
filenames = ["parts-"+str(i) for i in range(1,105)] #creating filename


for file in filenames: 
    input_filename = file + ".csv" #adding extension to import
    data = pd.read_csv(input_filename) 

    #your code to translate: 

    translations = {}
    for column in data.columns:
        unique = data[column].unique()
        for element in unique:
        translations[element] = translator.translate(element).text

    #creating corresponding output files

    data.replace(translations, inplace = True)
    output_filename = file + "-translated.csv" 
    data.to_csv(output_filename)
```